# Read simple csv with PySpark

Tags: csv, pyspark, data-science-experience

probably a silly issue, but I don't get it. I'm working on a Jupyter Notebook with Python3.6, Spark 2.4, hosted by IBM Watson Studio.

I have a simple csv file:

```
num,label
0,0
1,0
2,0
3,0
```

And to read it I use the following commands:

```
labels = spark.read.csv(url, sep=',', header=True)
```

But if I check if `labels` is correct, using `labels.head()`, I get `Row(PAR1Љ��L�Q��  ='\x08\x00]')`

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like due to an encoding issue

Try this with an encoding provided in the option,alo try with UTF-8

```
labels = spark.read.csv(url, sep=',', header=True).option("encoding", "ISO-8859-1")
```

Comment: Indeed the ISO-8859-1 encoding did the job. However, stated like that do not work.
I ran `labels = spark.read.csv(url, sep=',', header=True, encoding="ISO-8859-1")`